# Engineering basic question: speed of a device designed in FPGA

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, speed, vivado

I am studying FPGA by myself, sorry if it is a stupid question for you.

1. I am going to design a block in FPGA ( vivado/vhdl). This block will transmit data. I need to reach for this block, for example 10 mbits/s transmission speed.

What is a transmission speed? Is it clock signal?

EDIT 1: I am working on SPI master design block

2. Block as state machine design

is each state a process in vhdl design?

Comment: Can you explain what the block is ? or the name of the block?

Comment: @HariKrishna It will be a SPI master block

Comment: It depends on how many bits per clock you want to send. Simple SPI interfaces transfer 1 bit per clock.

Comment: @Justme So...clk defines a speed of the transmission?

Comment: The clock to the logic block would normally be greater than the SPI master SCLK. SPI is pretty simple - output data on one edge of the clock, receive data on the alternate edge.

Comment: @Kartman basic of SPI ( how clk and spi clk work) I have learnt.  I dont know what I have to change if i need to improve a speed of the transmission. This is my question!

Comment: Transmission speed is the speed it transmits. How it's related to clock speed depends how you write it. No, typically (but there are other styles) a state machine can be written as a single process, and that's the simplest and most reliable way to do it.

Comment: @user_1818839 Can i rewrite a state machine design as a combination of processes? For example, state 1 is a process 1, ...,  state N is a process N..

Comment: I'm not going to say you can't. I AM going to say that will be much more difficult for no benefit. For one thing, a signal should only be driven by one process (see "multiple drivers in VHDL") so an output driven by different states becomes much more difficult. So much that in a quarter century using VHDL I've never seen it done. What would you hope to gain by such a rewrite?

Comment: @FrankiLee, (if this is what's behind your comment here) yes, you can design it using separate processes (circuits) for the SPI clock generation, transfer bit counting, enabling of tx/rx, serial shift registers. This is usually much clearer and simpler to follow. You don't have to to use an FSM, which can be harder to follow, especially as such an FSM would have embedded counters and shift registers and not be just an FSM anyway.

Answer (score 3):

SPI has a basic clock rate (e.g., 10Mbit/s) and is one bit wide by default. Wider versions are available: 2, 4 and 8 bits. Advanced versions even use a double-data-rate clock.

At 10Mbit/s, your timing is pretty relaxed and should be easy to meet even with the slowest 7 Series device. You should be able to easily close timing at 50MHz or so without doing anything exotic. Faster than that takes more work, such as careful use of IOB flops and some fiddling with the read data capture clock to deal with the read turn-around delay.

Speaking of 'closing timing', part of your design task includes making proper constraints for your SPI interface, using **SDC (Synopsys Design Constraints)** directives. This is the stuff that goes into the .xdc file, along with the other things like I/O pad placement and type.

I can't emphasize this enough: **if you care about speed, you need to learn and use SDC directives**. Otherwise the synthesis and place/route flows won't know how to optimize your design, and you'll have no meaningful way to know if your design will work at your target speed.

When you get to the point of actually making SDC constraints, the Xilinx community sites are a good resource ([avrumw](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/7227) is the man when it comes to SDC.) There's lots of questions for SPI constraints; plenty of fellow travelers are doing the same thing.

Finally, as you think about your architecture, I encourage you to look at the Vivado IP library's AXI SPI master/slave peripheral. It would be well worth your time to study it before you set out to design your own. More here: https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/axi_quadspi.html

Comment: avrumw is indeed the life saver in xilinx forums. 

Comment: Dear hacktastical, thank you for taking time to reply. I read the SPI Quard documentation, but I decided  ISPI slave/master I will design  in VHDL. Slave is done, I will work on a master block. My main problem is I dont know how to increase a speed of SPI up to 50-100 Mbits/s. I am a beginner and probably for you they are stupid questions, I am sorry.  I have found I need a DMA block between SPI slave or master and CPU.  Should DMA be improved for improving SPI speed?